# Is it possible to make TypeScript's tsc use the Array<Item> syntax rather than Item[] for errors and warnings?

Tags: arrays, typescript

TS has [two syntaxes for arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays):

> To specify the type of an array like `[1, 2, 3]`, you can use the
> syntax `number[]`; this syntax works for any type (e.g. `string[]` is
> an array of strings, and so on). You may also see this written as
> `Array<number>`, which means the same thing.

I dislike the `Item[]` syntax as it seems inconsistent with the rest of the language, e.g. `Partial<Item>` or `Promise<Array<Item>>`, etc. It also occasionally leads to user error where I misread:

```
{ 
  date: Date,
  age: number 
}[]
```

as:

```
{ 
  date: Date,
  age: number 
}
```

I use the generic syntax in my code, but `tsc` errors as reported in VS Code use the shorthand syntax:

[image]

Is is possible to make `tsc` always use the `Array<Item>` syntax (in errors, type descriptions, etc.)?

Comment: What do you mean _use_? That's what _you write_ in the source code, you can definitely just use `Array<Type>` if you want to. Do you mean make `tsc` refuse to compile `Type[]`? What about [linting rules](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/array-type.md)?

Comment: What is preventing you from writing `Array<{ date: Date, age: number}>`?

Comment: By 'use' I mean in errors and type descriptions from `tsc` (hence mentioning tsc in the question). Obviously my own code uses `Array<Item>`

Comment: @MaartenDev I am asking about tsc output, hence mentioning `tsc` in the question. Obviously I can use either syntax to write my code, as also mentioned in the question.

Comment: The error specifies that an Array of that type cannot be assigned to a `ConcatArray` and you do not show enough code of where this is used to troubleshoot. Check your destination type.

Comment: @crashmstr the question is not about that specific error, but the fact that it shows shorthand syntax `Thing[]` not generic syntax `Array<Thing>`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware that's not configurable, no.